# Redis do not get escape sequence

Tags: redis, command-line-interface

Redis document in redis.io at `redis-cli` have escape sequence table with `new-line` \n, `tab` \t ... as many others language. But when i run it on terminal, bizzard thing happen. As expecting, we should see Hello on a line and World on another, but both connected with double slash and 'n'.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET mykey 'Hello\nWorld'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET mykey
"Hello\\nWorld"
```

I do exactly by the tutorial on redis official, so i can not know what happen. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET mykey_single 'Hello\nWorld'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> SET mykey_double "Hello\nWorld"
OK
```

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET mykey_single
"Hello\\nWorld"
127.0.0.1:6379> GET mykey_double
"Hello\nWorld"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: How it help? It's even more weird to me. What i image is `Hello` on 1 line an `World` is the line below. Now, in sigle quotes version, it just translate a slash to double slash. in double quotes version, it keep nothing change. To make it clearer, In the tutorial of redis.io, 2 those worlds appear in 2 line.

Comment: This is just CLI view. Try running `redis-cli GET mykey > log.txt; cat log.txt` from your terminal

Comment: Thank you so much, but i still don't get why  in single quote version, it make double slash? Seemly a reverse escape sequence process. What i know is both single and double quote present String, and in String, /n become new line

Comment: And I also test `redis-cli GET mykey > log.txt; gedit log.txt`. The same return is `Hello\nWorld`